# Regular expression for match

Tags: java, regex

How to find such lines in a file

```
########     this_is_a_line.sh     ########
```

I tried the below regular expression but it does not work

```
(#)+( )+(A-Za-z0-9_)+(.sh)( )+(#)+
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone let me know what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used `(...)` (a [*capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) instead of `[...]` (a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)). Use the character class:

```
#+ +[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.sh +#+
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM9lI7/2) (note most of the capture groups are redundant here, and I removed them. Also, `.` must be escaped to match a literal dot.)

The `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` matches 1 or more letters, digits or `_`.

The `(A-Za-z0-9_)+` matches 1 or more *sequences* of `A-Za-z0-9_` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM9lI7/3)).

Also, in Java, you can use `\w` to match `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and [shorten your regex](https://regex101.com/r/iM9lI7/4) to

```
#+ +\w+\.sh +#+
```

Do not forget that you need to double each `\` in the pattern string in Java (`String pattern = "#+ +\\w+\\.sh +#+";`).